# How to set focus on a section of my web page then scroll down click on an element and again scroll down to view the elements visible on opening

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am able to scroll to a section of the website, and click on the element. But my test fails as the elements opening on the click is not visible without scrolling again.

This is the code I used to scroll and click:

```
var filter = theSwitch.pageBar;
            var scrollIntoView = function () {
              arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
            };
          browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, filter);
          theSwitch.pageBar.click();
```

Comment: Can you give more info about what you want, what is visible after the first click and so on? Also some HTML-code examples?

Comment: If you knew that the element to be clicked is not visible because you lack additional scroll, why not add a line to scroll down before clicking again?